# get the next row in a table-javascript

Tags: javascript

how wud u get the next row in the following example? (i am trying to print the next three row/column values of the rowId provided)

```
function printRowData(rowId)
{
    var row=document.getElementById(rowId);
    for(i=0; i<3 ; i++)
    {
        var column=row.getElementsByTagName("td");
        alert(column[0].innerText);

        //now i want to move to the next row...something like row=row.next()?????
     }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you just want the next row, and not subsequent rows, you can do this:

```
var next = row.parentNode.rows[ row.rowIndex + 1 ];
```

So your code could look like this:

```
function printRowData(rowId) {
    var row=document.getElementById(rowId);
    var idx = row.rowIndex;
    for(i=0; i<4 ; i++) {
        if( row ) {
            alert(row.cells[0].innerText);
           var row = row.parentNode.rows[ ++idx ];
        }
    }
}
```

From the current row, it gets the `.parentNode`, then from that, it accesses the `rows` collection, and increments the `.rowIndex` property of the original row to select the next.

This takes care of white space issues.

*Notice also that instead of `getElementsByTagName`, I replaced it with `row.cells`, which is a collection of the cells in the row.*

---

**EDIT:** *Forgot to include the `rows` property after `parentNode`. It was included in the description though. Fixed.*

Comment: Thanks alot jason...but i want atleast three rows or may b more, to be printed..and secondly if i do "row.rowIndex + 1" it is skipping the next immediate row!!

Comment: @Salman: It does not skip the next row. Is the `for` loop intended for the sake of getting 3 rows instead of one? What exactly should the code do? http://jsfiddle.net/GbEEg/

Comment: ...if you want to get the first cell content of the given row, plus two more, [here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/GbEEg/1/).

Answer (score 3):

To get around the problems with whitespace you can now use

```
row = row.nextElementSibling
```

Just make sure to check for null when you get to the end of the table, or if you have a `thead`, `tbody` or `tfoot` it will be at the end of that particular node.

If you're supporting older browsers you may want to use a shim.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `nextSibling` property:

```
row = row.nextSibling
```

But note that whitespace in your source HTML may turn into text nodes among the rows. You may have to call `nextSibling` more than once to skip the text nodes.

Have you considered using jQuery? With jQuery, you don't have to worry about the text nodes:

```
row = $("#" + rowId);
...
row = row.next();
```

Comment: Not sure, but this may depend on how the `table` is coded.  Whitespace between the `tr`s could be interpreted as the `.nextSibling`.

Comment: This will break in W3C compliant browsers.

Comment: @Jaso, @patrick: That's correct, as I've already stated in my updated answer. And I don't suppose jQuery would have a problem with its `next()` implementation...

Comment: @Ates.  I looked at that.  I think jQuery's `next()` would not have a problem, especially if you use a selector expression like `next('tr')`

Answer (score 0):

`row = row.nextSibling`. You might need to do that in a while loop as you may come across whitespace nodes, so you should check to see if the next node has the correct tagName.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, then it's becoming really easy.

```
row.next();
```

Comment: You don't need to load an entire library just to select the next row in a table.

Answer (score -1):

Use `document.getElementById(rowId).nextSibling`